# Facebook Graph API. How to get comment from post

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi i have this to get comment from post it works is there is a years

```
 $json = file_get_contents("http://graph.facebook.com/730350233684840/comments?limit=2500");
    echo $json;
```

but now i have this error in facebook

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104
   }
}
```

how i can get all comment from post ?

i have using your code @luschn 
my request with true APP ID and App Secret

```
https://graph.facebook.com/730350233684840/comments?limit=2500&access_token=[APPIS|APPSECRT]
```

i have this

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid OAuth access token signature.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 190
   }
}
```

i use chrome to look this error

--
English is not my native language, sorry for any mistakes.

Comment: well, do what it says in the error message. use an access token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to change the position access token and limit

```
https://graph.facebook.com/167416583311544_730350233684840/comments?access_token=appId|appSecret&limit=2500
```

Answer (score 3):

For example:

```
$json = file_get_contents("http://graph.facebook.com/730350233684840/comments?limit=2500&access_token=[your-access-token]");
```

The most basic Access Token is an App Access Token, you can create one like this:

```
$appAccesstoken = $appId . '|' . $appSecret;
```

Depending on the resource, you may need a User or Page Token though. For that, you will have to authorize the User and it gets a lot more complicated.

More information about Access Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: thank you but how can I create an access token manual because I will use my code in an infinite loop

Comment: $appAccesstoken = $appId . '|' . $appSecret;

Comment: i use your code but shi not works i have Invalid OAuth access token signature.

Comment: then you are not doing it correctly. post your code in your question.

Comment: and make sure you know all the tools facebook offers. for example there is a debugger that can debug open graph tags and access tokens.

Comment: ...remove the brackets around the token. and NEVER EVER post your app secret ANYWHERE...you really need to learn the basics of dealing with the facebook api ;)

Comment: as i said, remove the brackets...it´s a normal get parameter, i just put it in brackets to show you where the token starts and ends.

Comment: when I remove the brackets  `https://graph.facebook.com/730350233684840/comments?limit=2500&access_token=IDAPP|SECRET` have this error `"message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",`

Comment: What kind of post is this? Is it on a user profile, or on a page? If it is on a user profile, you need to ask the user for permission to read the post first; if it is on a page and that page is somehow restricted, then you need to use a page access token (which means you must have admin access to the page), or a user access token for a user that can see the post.

Comment: @CBroe it is for a facebook page whose content is public like this post  [page facebook](https://www.facebook.com/ilovebenimellal/posts/730350233684840:0)

Comment: Well in that case, you can simply use your app access token (since it is server-side code – if it was client-side code, that would be an absolute no-no, because from client-side code, everyone could steal the token.) Looks like you need to use the “full” id though, consisting of `page id underscore post id`: `https://graph.facebook.com/167416583311544_730350233684840/comments?limit=2500&access_token=…`

Comment: @ CBroe thank you but when i do this `https://graph.facebook.com/167416583311544_730350233684840/comments?limit=2500&‌​access_token=appId|appSecret` i have this message `"message": "An access token is required to request this resource."` how i can generate the right access token ?

Comment: i just tried it in the api explorer, works fine with an app token: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=167416583311544_730350233684840%2Fcomments%3Flimit%3D2500&

Comment: put your token into the debugger to find out if it´s a valid one: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/